# MySQL rank calculation with all entries at 0

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL script which ranks a set of users in a leaderboard table.

```
UPDATE leaderboard
JOIN   (SELECT f.winnings ,
IF     (@lastPoint <> f.winnings,
        @curRank := @curRank +1, 
        @curRank) AS rank, 
        @lastPoint := f.winnings
FROM   leaderboard f
JOIN   (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0) r
WHERE f.competition =5
ORDER BY f.winnings DESC
) ranks ON (ranks.winnings = leaderboard.winnings)
SET leaderboard.rank = ranks.rank WHERE leaderboard.id =89;
```

However when all users have a rank of 0 it does not rank them as 1 (i.e equal) this behaviou only occurs for 0.

```
winnings  rank
0          0
0          0
0          0
```

Would anyone know how to do this..?

```
winnings  rank
0          1
0          1
0          1
```

SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53c3a/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<>` test fails

```
UPDATE leaderboard
JOIN   (SELECT f.winnings ,
IF     (@lastPoint <> f.winnings,
        @curRank := @curRank +1, 
        @curRank) AS rank, 
        @lastPoint := f.winnings
FROM   leaderboard f
JOIN   (SELECT @curRank :=0, @lastPoint :=-1) r
ORDER BY f.winnings DESC
) ranks ON (ranks.winnings = leaderboard.winnings)
SET leaderboard.rank = ranks.rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `@LastPoint` to an invalid value:

```
UPDATE leaderboard
JOIN   (SELECT f.winnings ,
IF     (@lastPoint <> f.winnings,
        @curRank := @curRank +1, 
        @curRank) AS rank, 
        @lastPoint := f.winnings
FROM   leaderboard f
JOIN   (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := -1) r
ORDER BY f.winnings DESC
) ranks ON (ranks.winnings = leaderboard.winnings)
SET leaderboard.rank = ranks.rank;
```